# Spring-XD spring application for bigdata

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-xd

I'm new to Spring-XD and only have basic idea that it helps in storing huge data in hadoop as files. I would like to develop my application to save data coming into socket using Spring-XD to hadoop.

Is this possible ?
If yes can anyone point me to some examples where it has been done ?
Please do not redirect me to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd. It does not contain any example of how to write a file to hadoop and connection configuration of hadoop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) as it is the successor of Spring XD. You can make use of [hdfs](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/hdfs) source/sink application based on whether you need to read/write from/to HDFS.

You can still try out Spring XD samples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples) to get an idea.